# Format entire row if a particular cell in the row is not empty

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to format the whole row depending on if a particular cell in that is empty or not. I want conditional formatting to go through all rows and say add a background color if column C in that row is not empty.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 50):

For illustration assuming "whole row" is ColumnsA:Z inclusive, please try Format - Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is**:

```
=$C1<>""
```

with formatting of your choice and *Range:* `A:Z`.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. My range was `A2:D999` so that it didn't include the title row.

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cuse-custom-formulas-with-conditional-formatting

Answer (score 11):

I was able to do this by selecting the range I want the conditional formatting to apply to (for instance, `A:P` if you want to apply colour to columns A through P), and then selecting "Custom formula is" and adding `=LEN($C:$C)>0`. Then you just need to select the colour you want to apply.

Answer (score 1):

The new Google Sheets can do some of this.
Follow the instructions here: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/78413?hl=en

Summary: Format menu => Conditional formatting => "Text contains" drop down menu, select "Custom formula is" => Type "=isblank(C2)" => Add background color => Add range (like: A2:D2)

Although it does not solve completely the question, you will be able to define one rows color based on a cell's value.

Hope it helped.

P.s: While I was testing it I have encountered some bugs in this feature so it may very well happen that it won't be really useful. We'll see...

Comment: I got it to work for a selection by selecting the column you want the format applied to and enter in a formula like the following:    =IF(ISBLANK($B2:B),false,true)     <<  This means if the column B is not empty in that row, then the column I am formatting will become whatever format I wanted it to be.   The ${COLNAM}:{COLNAME} format appears to suggest a range

Answer (score 0):

Adding to pnuts' solution, if you're skipping header rows you need to start the enumeration skipping them, as well.

For Example: If you're skipping 1 row, the new formula would be:

```
$C2<>""
```

Answer (score -1):

Little late of an answer but hopefully it will help anyone searching:

=IF(a2="",false,true)

And select your range to format, with A2 being something in the range (not sure if this matters).

Works for conditional formatting.