# IF Statement in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I am having some issues with the below formula. I want cells L6 and L7 multiplying in M6:M7 if both L6 and L7 are populated, which seems to have worked.

However, if both cells aren't populated like seen in the image, I need cells M6:M7 to be blank rather than 0, as the 0 is affecting the overall average off column M.

[image: See Image Below]

Comment: [google sheets - Format entire row if a particular cell in the row is not empty - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170130/format-entire-row-if-a-particular-cell-in-the-row-is-not-empty)

Comment: I dont want to add illustration?I want M6:M7 to be blank because L7 is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at changing the average calculation as blank can be taken a zero for some calculations.

In excel I would look at averageifs() and excluding zero values such as :

```
=averageifs(A1:A10,A1:A10,">"&0)
```

See
[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is how you should do it:

```
=IF(COUNTA(L6:L7)=2, IF(L6:L7>0, L6*L7, ), )
```